# Firefox OS - mozMobileConnection doesn't exist in navigator

Tags: javascript, firefox, operating-system, mozilla, navigator

I'm currently developing on Firefox OS and I have to handle mobile connection so I've read some tutorials and the documentation from Mozilla and I found the `navigator` object and one of its attribute `mozMobileConnection`.

Unfortunatelly, this atrtibute doesn't exist... I don't really know why. Anybody got an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this !

I didn't add any permission in my manifest and my application wasn't "certified". I'd just have to add these lines :

```
  "type":"certified",
  "permissions": {
    "mobileconnection": {
      "description": "Required for handle mobile connection"
    }
  }
```

I hope this will help others !